# Import module that is called with sys args

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a python code (A) that needs parameters and modules from another python code (B) but B is run with system arguments (python B.py 30 10). How do I import B in A?

Comment: This depends entirely on how `B` works. If it only does minimal work at top level, putting most of its logic into a function that it calls, then it's probably easy to import it and call that function yourself. If it is just a pure script with all its code at the top level, then it may be impractical to `import` it at all.

Comment: B.py is being run as a python script and may not be import safe. You could experiment. Its a bit hacky, but A.py could set parameters in `sys.argv` and import B. If all goes well, B runs, does its argv thing and ... well ... maybe works. If it has `if __name__ == "__main__:"`, or expects to exit, all could go terribly wrong.

Comment: I think the real answer is to refactor B. Extract all of its wanted functionality into functions in a different .py file that is intended to be imported. Now the scheleton B.py does command line parsing, then imports this new .py for the real work.

Comment: Thank you all. These are very helpful